# Apache CXF and Spring AOP

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, spring-aop

I have deployed a Web service using Apache Came and Apache CXF and "code first" approach. It works fine.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="operacionesWSEndpoint" address="/operaciones"
    serviceClass="foo.bar.OperacionesService">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

but I want to measure the performance of my service and log it. For that, I use Spring AOP using the following pointcut

```
@Pointcut("execution(* foo.bar.OperacionesService.*(..))")
public void operacionsMethods() {

}

@Around("operacionsMethods()")
public Object logTimeMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    StopWatch stopWatch =
            new StopWatch(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + "."
                + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    stopWatch.start();

    Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

    stopWatch.stop();

    log.debug("performance: {}", stopWatch.shortSummary());

    return retVal;
}
```

Well, is not working. Other methods and services are being logged using the same approach (AOP), but not the Web Service exposed by Camel.

I don't think there is any error with my code: service is working as well as other aspects. I feel I am missing something here regarding Apache Camel - CXF and Spring AOP and I did not find a similar problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: years ago asked, but still - did you find a solution to this back then?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried camel and Spring AOP, but you could use a camel [interceptor](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html), as an alternative. This isn't quiet what you wanted. 
Also, for measuring you could use a 'meter' and Slf4jReporter from the [metrics library](http://metrics.codahale.com/).